# Hypothesis test chi square

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test

I'm an statistics/R beginner.

I want do to a chi square test to compare two categorical variables.
The first one (predictor) has 2 levels/binary (0,1), the second one 5 (0,1,2,3,4).

Does it matter for the chi squared that the first variable has 0 = 173 while 1 = 30? Or do they have to be close to each other so they are comparable

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please take the tour to learn how to ask questions here that are likely to get relevant answers.

Comment: What do you mean by "compare" those two variables? Wouldn't it make more sense that you compare the distribution of the second variable at each level of the first? i.e.compare the distribution of the second one when "first variable = 0" vs the second variable when "first variable = 1" (details of what your variables were would have made that much less difficult to clearly express). That is, rather that compare those two variables, wouldn't you instead be interested in homogeneity of proportions in one variable as the levels of the other changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have a $2\times 5$ table, such as `TAB` below,
where rows are for responses $0$ and $1$ and columns
are for scores $0$ through $4.$

```
TAB
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   15   31   42   62   22
[2,]   14   54   64   49   26
```

If so, then in R, you could do a `chisq.test` on the counts in `TAB`
as follows:

```
chisq.test(TAB)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TAB
X-squared = 9.529, df = 4, p-value = 0.04916
```

For my fictitious data, the chi-squared test finds
that Likert counts are not independent of $0$'s and $1$'s
(just barely) at the 5% level of significance
because the P-value $0.04916 < 0.05 = 5\%.$

```
chisq.test(TAB)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TAB
X-squared = 9.529, df = 4, p-value = 0.04916
```

I can imagine that with row totals 143 and 207, for
different data than mine, some column totals might be too
small for a successful chi-squared test. If so,
there may be cures for that; let us know.

Your question seems a bit vague. If you meant something else,
then please explain how the above differs from your intentions,
and maybe someone here can help.

You may also gain additional insights about using chi-squared tests
if you look at some of the pages marked 'Relevant' in the margin of this page.